# Excel Interop reading worksheet content

Tags: c#, excel, c++-cli, interop, cells

I know this is a very basic topic, but I've done research and yet haven't found a solution to my problem, which is getting the contents of a number of cells in a worksheet. This is what I have:

```
Excel::Application^ ExList = gcnew Excel::ApplicationClass();
ExList->DisplayAlerts = false;
ExList->Visible = false;
Workbook^  Wbook1  = ExList->Workbooks->Open(Glo::m_archive01, Type::Missing, false, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing,     Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing);
Worksheet^ Wsheet1 = safe_cast<Worksheet^>(ExList->ActiveSheet);
String^ m_new_section;//the variable to be displayed later on by means of MessageBox::Show(m_new_section);.
```

This is what I've tried and the compiler errors I've gotten:

```
m_new_section = Cells[5, 2]->Value;
error C2065: 'Cells' : undeclared identifier
error C2227: left of '->Value' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

m_new_section = ExList->Cells[5, 2]
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'System::String ^'

m_new_section = ExList->Cells[5, 2]->Value;
error C2039: 'Value' : is not a member of 'System::Object'

m_new_section = Wsheet1->Cells[5, 2];
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'System::String ^'

m_new_section = Wsheet1->Cells[5, 2]->Value;
error C2039: 'Value' : is not a member of 'System::Object'

m_new_section = ExList->Cells[5, 2]->Value.ToString();
error C2039: 'Value' : is not a member of 'System::Object'
error C2228: left of '.ToString' must have class/struct/union
```

This one actually "worked"

```
m_new_section = Wsheet1->Cells[5, 2]->ToString();
```

but all MessageBox showed for all the cells read was this string:  "System._ComObject".

What am I missing? A reference? Like I said before, I'm new at this and coding in c++/cli. My only references are examples I've found written in c#.

At this point, I'd appreciate any heLp. THANK YOU!

Comment: So, Mr. Stokes, what's you input, sir?

Answer (score 0):

"Funny how time teaches us patience. The older we get, the greater our capacity for waiting" - Elizabeth Taylor.

```
String^ m_new_section;
Excel::Range^ er1 = Wsheet1->Range["E2:E2", Type::Missing];
m_new_section = er1->Text->ToString();
```

That's all that needed to be done. Again, THANKS FOR YOUR TIME! Thanks, Chris!